# Create Multimap from Map<K,Collection<V>> with key as V[0] and value as K using Java 8

Tags: java-8, guava

I have a `Map<String,List<String>>`(say inputMap) and I want to convert this to another `Map<String,List<String>>` where each (k,v) in the new map is (v.get(0),k) of inputMap.

Ex.

```
X -> B,C,D
Y -> B,D,E
Z -> B,G,H
P -> A,B,D
Q -> A,D,F
R -> A,C,B
```

to

```
B->X,Y,Z
A->P,Q,R
```

I initially thought I could do this using something like

```
inputMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue.get(0),Map.Entry::getKey));
```

and then converting this map to a multimap, but I cannot write `Map.Entry::getValue.get(0)`

It would also be great if I could create the multimap in `.collect()` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect directly into a `Multimap`:

```
Multimap<String, String> result = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(
                ArrayListMultimap::create,
                (mm,e) -> mm.put(e.getValue().get(0), e.getKey()),
                Multimap::putAll
        );
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Map<String, List<String>> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        //create new entries mapping B to X, B to Y, B to Z etc.
        .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getValue().get(0), e.getKey()))
        //we group by the key (B or A) and we collect the values into a list
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Comment: This works, but I think this a bit too verbose compared  to the alternative of doing it using plain for loops. Maybe its not time to go nuts on java 8 functional programming yet...

Answer (score 1):

Method references don’t work that way. If you can’t express a function as a reference to a *single* method, you need a lambda expression.

Further, the `toMap` collector is not the best choice when you want multiple values, `groupingBy` is the right tool here.

```
Map<String,List<String>> result=map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(e->e.getValue().get(0),
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```